# Adding remaining filed in $project after adding lookups in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm doing a $lookup from an _id in Order schema, and its working as expected. But in `$project` how to add remaining keys. I have added my code below.

**Product Collection:**

```
{
"_id": "54759eb3c090d83494e2d804",
"product_name": "sample product",
"image": "default.png",
"price": 55,
"discount": 5,
}
```

**Order list Collection**

```
   {
        "user_name": "sample1",
        "product_list":[
        {
          "product_id": "54759eb3c090d83494e2d804"
          "quantity": 5
        }
        ]
    }
```

**lookups**

```
[
      {
        from: 'product',
        localField: 'product_list.product_id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'product_list.product_id',
        model: 'ProductModel',
      },
    ],
```

**$Project**

```
{
      user_name: true,
      product_list: {
        $map: {
          input: '$product_list.product_id',
          as: 'product',
          in: {
            product_name: '$$product.product_name',
          },
        },
      },
    }
```

**Current Result:**

```
{
    "user_name": "sample1",
    "product_list":[
       "product_id":{
          "product_name": "sample product"
        }
     ]
}
```

In this current result, the quantity field is missing. How to add in `$project`?. The expected result shown below

**Expected Result:**

```
   {
      "user_name": "sample1",
       "product_list":[
           {
               "product_id": {
                    "product_name": "sample product"
                }
               "quantity": 5
           }
         ]
   }
```

Comment: after the look up what would be the output?

Comment: Output was like **Current Result**

Comment: post some sample of product collection

Comment: @varman, I have updated product collection above

Comment: I am checking that, till then deleted my answer

Comment: when you use lookup, it will give you an array of product. Does that mean you have only one to one relationship?

Comment: Actually I'm new to these concepts, then is there any other way to do that?

Comment: @SudharsanVenkatraj does below answer your question? let me know if you are getting any problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `$unwind` before `$lookup`, because it will not work directly in array fields, and here you don't need $map inside $project,

- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `product_list` deconstruct array

```
db.order.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$product_list" },
```

- [$lookup with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries), this will allow to use pipeline inside lookup, here `$project` to required fields

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "product",
      as: "product_list.product_id",
      let: { product_id: "$product_list.product_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$product_id", "$_id"] }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            product_name: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

- `$unwind` with path `product_list.product_id` because you need it as object

```
  { $unwind: { path: "$product_list.product_id" } },
```

- [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by `_id` re-construct your `product_list` array

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      user_name: { $first: "$user_name" },
      product_list: { $push: "$product_list" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fONUkI7gi3I)

Comment: You got me a minute before :)

Comment: Opps sorry guys, just made it and post.

Comment: No issues @turivishal :) Keep rocking all

Comment: @turivishal haha, that was awesome

Comment: Might be this is disrespecting you, i never seen your comments with OP, just come here and read question and answered within 3 minutes :(

Comment: No bro, what you are doing is totally fine.... You dont need to wait for anyone. Obviously I'm learning from answers too :D